# JavaScript regex not replacing '@' character

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I am new to JavaScipt and testing a regular Expression and is working on below use case -

Requirement - Replace every character with '#' that is **NOT FROM BELOW LIST**-

- Number
- Character (upper or lower case)
- Any special character except -> comma, dot, square brackets, forward slash, single Quote

Please find my code below -

```
    var replacedStr = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9'.-\[\], ]/g,"#");
```

Output for various values of str are -

```
   str = "hello_";
   replacedStr is hello#
   _______________________
   str = "hello@_";
   replacedStr is hello@#
```

I wanted to know why '@' isnot being replaced from above regex.

The same behavior is with characters - underScore, question-Mark, Angular brackets.

Please guide.

Thanks,

Vibhav

Comment: As it does in A-Z, the dash in .-\[ is creating a range of characters

Answer (score 2):

In your original regex, your dash (hyphen) is being interpreted as a range:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9'.-\[\], ]
```

This is being intepreted as the range of characters from dot `.` until opening bracket `[`, which *includes* the at symbol.  If you move the hyphen to the very end of the negated character class, the regex will work as intended:

```js
str = "hello@_";
str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9'.\[\], -]/g,"#");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of mistakes in your reg-ex you have to put '-' in front of charachter class (or at last).

Below reg-ex will do the trick

```
/[^.,\[\]\\'a-zA-Z0-9]/g
```

you can use online testers like http://www.regexpal.com/ to check regex's

Answer (score 0):

Hyphen will be taken as a range, hence you need to add a escape sequence to it.

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9'.\-\[\]]/g,"#");
```